# Magento how to make quick access links as dropdown

Tags: magento, drop-down-menu

I want to replace static `quick access` links like `(myaccount, login, Checkout, links)`to a dropdown. Like My account should be visible, is user clicks my account it should show all remaining links as dropdown....

Did anyone tried this before.? Please give me your suggestions to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no quick way. You definitely can modify `template/page/template/links.phtml` and `template/page/template/linksblock.phtml` to show `<select>` and `<option>` instead of `<ul>` and `<li>` but this will change links list into drop down for all instances of `<block type="page/template" ../>` which is already a footer links.

Comment: linksblock.phtml is not available in custom theme path : app\design\frontend\default\theme327k\template\page\template,shall i copy from app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\template and put into app\design\frontend\default\theme327k\template\page\template and make changes is right option?